# Unhandled exception at mfh265enc.dll

Tags: ms-media-foundation, h.265

I'm trying to encode video with H.265 encoder MFT on Win10 Pro Insider Preview.

- Originally I create/init an H.265 encoder in my own program and call ProcessInput/ProcessOuput and it crashed inside ProcessOuput (It didn't crash on first frame, instead it crashed after several frames have been processed).
- To simplify the question, I used IMFSinkWriter to create a sink, so frame encoding/writing thus is totally handled by sinkwriter. But unfortunately crash still happened inside mfh265enc.dll.

  Please note that in above 2 cases, the change I made was on a program which can successfully encode H.264 video. I only changed the output media type for Encoder/SinkWriter (changed subtype from H.264 to H.265). The way video frames got constructed, supplied to encoder/sinkwriter keep same. When encoding with H.264 everything was good, but once changed to H.265 it crashed.
- Then I turned to the sample program comes with **Win7 SDK: MFCaptureToFile** which could capture video into a MP4 file.

  I'm sure the video format from camera is acceptable to H.265 encoder.

  The only change I've done is to the outputmedia type which is passed to SinkWrite.AddStream.

  I've changed the subtype to MFVideoFormat_HEVC, and set MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE to 1 (eAVEncH265VProfile_Main_420_8).

  But with the 2 changes above, the program still crashes. Showing "Unhandled exception at 0x5A025085 (mfh265enc.dll) in MFCaptureToFile.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF"

  Here's the change I've made to the MFCaptureToFile program.
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/oytqen13m7bcs23/DIFF.PNG?dl=0

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: Can you share which Windows 10 build you're on, as well as your graphics card and driver version?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm running a Win10 Pro Insider preview. From the settings I saw the product id is 00362-10000-00000-AA814. I think that's a software encoder comes with Windows, it should have nothing to do with graphics card.

Comment: If you open the "System Information" view (accessible from search), the exact version should be available under System Summary > Version - please include that along with your GPU and driver, which may be relevant. There's been a lot of bug fixes since the Insider program began, so the exact build is important. (I'm on the Media team at Microsoft, and you'd be surprised how relevant the GPU and driver can be, as well.) Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chris, the OS version is 10.0.10162 Build 10162. I'm using an integrated graphics card with Intel G45/G43 Express Chipset. In the device manager, following the device name, it shows "Microsoft Corporation -WDDM 1.1", from the "driver" page, I can see the "driver provider" is Intel, "driver date" 3 Nov 2013, "driver version": 8.15.10.2702

Comment: I've been looking at this and I am able to repro on the latest public Windows build, and it looks like this is indeed a bug. I'm planning on digging deeper into it tomorrow, and I'll post an answer with more information when I have it. For now, this problem didn't repro when I built in the x64 profile, so you may be able to get unblocked if that's acceptable for you.

Comment: Hi Chris, have you got any progress on this? Actually yesterday I found another issue on Win8/10, could you kindly have a look at it? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d3294de7-c817-4aa1-804d-fbae6d1ab45e/different-behavior-of-h264-encoder-mft-on-win7-and-win8?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to follow up! I believe somebody's fixed the issue but I'm not sure when it's scheduled to be released. I may not find out until closer to the release date, but I'll try to let you know. I'll take a look at your forum post in the morning as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the RTM release of Windows 10 (build 10240), and any prior Windows Insider releases.

I can confirm that this bug has been fixed in [the latest Insider build (10532)](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/08/27/windows-10-insider-preview-build-10532-for-pc/), but at this time there is no public release date for when the fix will be pushed to all Windows users.

I have noticed that the problem does not occur on an x64 build in Visual Studio, so if building a 64-bit version of the application is an acceptable workaround, that may help to unblock people until this fix is public.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just ran a test on Build 10532 and yes I was able to encode and then get a file. But as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt131743(v=vs.85).aspx "After the output type is set, the video encoder updates the type by adding the MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER attribute. This attribute contains the sequence header."   But on my machine, pOutType->GetBlobSize(MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER, &size); returns "The requested attribute was not found". Without the sequence header, the MP4 file can't be player on Win10. Could you have a look at it when you're free

Comment: I was able to create playable HEVC encoded files under build 10240. However I do get random access violation errors during encoding fairly consistently now. And If the encode succeeds, it seems the resulting don't play back smoothly.

Comment: Still getting access violation exceptions when using H.265/HEVC in build 10547 Anyone else? This is in a 32bit app. Looks like it was not fixed.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just had another try on Win10 version 1511(OS Build 10586.17)  32-bit using MFCaptureToFile sample poject with these changes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oytqen13m7bcs23/DIFF.PNG?dl=0  It could generate a MP4 file, but can't be opened even on Win10. Could you have a look at it